# Assign options in destructure

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I've tried to rewrite the following code according to ES6. I keep getting ESLint warnings, and I've spent about 20 minutes on it so far, I'm not quite sure how to write it...

```
  .then(result => {
    const [categories, properties, placements] = result.map(r => r.data);

    this.properties = properties.map(property => {
      {
        ...property,
        category: categories.find(c => c.id === property.category_id),
        property: placements.filter(p => p.property_id === property.id),
      }
    });
  });
```

The code above just doesn't parse at all, but depending on what I've tried it says I can't use return {} in an arrow function.

If I try to just modify the argument I get an error to `no-param-reassign`

Answer (score 0):

I realized I can run eslint fix to see how it would be done:

```
        this.properties = properties.map(property => ({
          ...property,
          category: categories.find(c => c.id === property.category_id),
          property: placements.filter(p => p.property_id === property.id),
        }));
```

Comment: To return an object from an arrow function, you either need to wrap the object in parentheses (like you did here) to avoid confusion with a function body or use the `return` keyword from within the function body.